# how can i get all Jenknis "GERRIT" parameters for a specifice for a scecific change via terminal

Tags: rest, jenkins, gerrit

i have a Jenkins build that work with gerrit.

i can re-trigger this job very easily throw Jenkins ui.

i wanted to re-trigger a specific build from the Linux terminal.

i manage to do it with a curl command when i input all the GERRIT parameters.

curl command:
curl  "url/job/job_name/buildWithParameters?token=token&GERRIT_CHANGE_ID=id_numberb&GERRIT_PATCHSET_REVISION=gerrit_patchset...

parameters:
GERRIT_PATCHSET_UPLOADER
GERRIT_PATCHSET_REVISION
GERRIT_CHANGE_ID
GERRIT_PATCHSET_NUMBER
GERRIT_EVENT_ACCOUNT_EMAIL
GERRIT_CHANGE_NUMBER
GERRIT_CHANGE_OWNER
GERRIT_REFSPEC1
GERRIT_EVENT_TYPE
GERRIT_EVENT_ACCOUNT
GERRIT_CHANGE_SUBJECT
GERRIT_CHANGE_OWNER_NAME
GERRIT_PROJECT
GERRIT_EVENT_HASH
GERRIT_BRANCH
GERRIT_CHANGE_OWNER_EMAIL
GERRIT_PATCHSET_UPLOADER_EMAIL
GERRIT_CHANGE_URL
GERRIT_PATCHSET_UPLOADER_NAME
GERRIT_EVENT_ACCOUNT_NAME

i only need a way to send 1 parameter from the above list and get all the rest.

i tried to curl the Jenkins/gerrit_manual_trigger/ , but i don't get this parameters.

how can i get all those parameters for a specific build via terminal?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to retrieve all Gerrit parameters with the following command:

```
curl -s -u USER:PASS --request GET "https://JENKINS-SERVER/JOB-PATHNAME/BUILD-NUMBER/api/json" | jq --raw-output '.actions[].parameters | select(length > 0) | .[] | .name + " " + .value'

GERRIT_EVENT_TYPE patchset-created
GERRIT_EVENT_HASH -1187252333
GERRIT_BRANCH master
...
GERRIT_PORT 29418
GERRIT_SCHEME ssh
GERRIT_VERSION 2.14.3
```

Comment: Hi liberman, did it work for your? Let the community knows the result...